# How to write a pyswip foreign predicate with multiple solutions?

Tags: python, prolog

I am trying to write a python method that when exposed to prolog has multiple solutions. I was thinking I could use `registerForeign`, but the project's examples don't indicate if it can be done. Here's a contrived example of what I want to do:

Imagine a predicate `active_user(X)` that unifies X to each active user on a website. Then in my prolog I could further filter X by other predicates i.e. `active_user(X), max_level(X)`

The python definition of `active_user` might look like so:

```py
def active_users(username):
  active_users = server.get_active_users() # List of strs
  for a in active_users:
    username.unify(a)
    yield
```

The above, of course, does not work. Here's another approach I tried:

```py
def active_users(username):
  username = list(server.get_active_users())
```

That didn't work either. The below example works however:

```py
def active_users(username):
  username.unify("george")
```

The examples directory contains a simple use of `registerForeign`, but it does not handle this case.
The only working solution I've come up with is to make the query in advance and then assert these values using `prolog.assertz` in a loop. But this is less flexible than what I'm imagining.

Thank you

EDIT: "george" does not work because it is a string (perhaps a separate question), but unifying an integer does work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though my answer comes a little late, I faced a very similar problem. Hence, I decided to share my solution.

You need to set the flag `PL_FA_NONDETERMINISTIC` to register a non-deterministic predicate. Otherwise, it will be registered as a deterministic predicate by default. In addition, you need one more parameter to keep track of the context of the call to your foreign predicate. E.g., if your predicate has arity 2, you will need 3 parameters, two for the arguments of the predicate itself and one additional for the context.

Inside your predicate, you need to extract the current context of the call (`PL_FIRST_CALL`, `PL_REDO`, or `PL_PRUNED`) and, if applicable, any information that you have returned to Prolog in the previous call (return with `PL_retry` and access with `PL_foreign_context`). The mechanism is analog to the one describe for C predicates in the SWI documentation (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=foreignnondet). For the usage with pyswip, you need to check the source code (https://github.com/yuce/pyswip).

Below is the code to return a list of users using a non-deterministic predicate. I tested it using Python 3.8.3 (Anaconda) and the most recent pyswip code from GitHub (July 20, 2020).

```
import pyswip


users = ["George", "Paul", "John", "Ringo"]


def active_users(username, handle):

    control = pyswip.core.PL_foreign_control(handle)

    index = None
    return_value = False

    if control == pyswip.core.PL_FIRST_CALL:  # First call of active_users
        index = 0

    if control == pyswip.core.PL_REDO:  # Subsequent call of active_users
        last_index = pyswip.core.PL_foreign_context(handle)  # retrieve the index of the last call
        index = last_index + 1

    if control == pyswip.core.PL_PRUNED:  # A cut has destroyed the choice point
        # Here we could do some clean up (not needed in this simple example)
        pass

    if index >= 0 and index < len(users):
        username.unify(users[index])
        return_value = pyswip.core.PL_retry(index)  # This allows us to retrieve the correct index in the next call to active_users

    return return_value


pyswip.registerForeign(active_users, arity=1, flags=pyswip.core.PL_FA_NONDETERMINISTIC)

prolog = pyswip.Prolog()

print(list(prolog.query("active_users(X)")))
```

When running the code, you should get the following output:

```
[{'X': 'George'}, {'X': 'Paul'}, {'X': 'John'}, {'X': 'Ringo'}]
```